# Sort paths by numeric sum

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following graph

```
(a1:A {name:'a1', s:1})  ->                            -> (a3:A {name:'a3',s:11})
(a2:A {name:'a2', s:10}) -> (b1:B) -> (c1:C) -> (b2:B) -> (a4:A {name:'a4',s:123})
```

On the left, there are 2 type A nodes that connect to the same type B node on the left. On the right, there are 2 type A nodes that connect to another type B node on the right. Each type A node has an attribute called `s` which indicates a score.

If I do a simple query like this

```
match p=((a1:A)--(b1:B)--(:C)--(b2:B)--(a2:A))
where a1.name in ['a1', 'a2']
return p
```

I will get 4 paths without any ordering. However, i would like the path to be order based on the aggregate score of the type A nodes on both end of the path, i.e,

```
(:A {name:'a2', s:10}) -> (b1:B) -> (c1:C) -> (b2:B) -> (:A {name:'a4',s:123})
(:A {name:'a1', s:1}) -> (b1:B) -> (c1:C) -> (b2:B) -> (:A {name:'a4',s:123})
(:A {name:'a2', s:10}) -> (b1:B) -> (c1:C) -> (b2:B) -> (:A {name:'a3',s:11})
(:A {name:'a1', s:1}) -> (b1:B) -> (c1:C) -> (b2:B) -> (:A {name:'a3',s:11})
```

Can I achieve this by cypher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add the score to each path:

```
match p=((a1:A)--(b1:B)--(:C)--(b2:B)--(a2:A))
where a1.name in ['a1', 'a2']
WITH p, a1.s + a2.s AS score
return p, score
ORDER BY score DESC
```

If I use it on this sample data:

```
MERGE (a1:A{name:'a1', s:1, key: 0})
MERGE (a2:A{name:'a2', s:10, key: 1})
MERGE (b1:B{key: 2})
MERGE (c1:C{key: 3})
MERGE (b2:B{key: 4})
MERGE (a3:A{name:'a3',s:11, key: 5})
MERGE (a4:A{name:'a4',s:123, key: 6})

MERGE (a1)-[:LINKS]-(b1)
MERGE (a2)-[:LINKS]-(b1)
MERGE (b1)-[:LINKS]-(c1)
MERGE (c1)-[:LINKS]-(b2)
MERGE (b2)-[:LINKS]-(a3)
MERGE (b2)-[:LINKS]-(a4)
```

The result is:

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤═══════╕
│"p"                                                                   │"score"│
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪═══════╡
│[{"name":"a2","s":10,"key":1},{},{"key":2},{"key":2},{},{"key":3},{"ke│133    │
│y":3},{},{"key":4},{"key":4},{},{"name":"a4","s":123,"key":6}]        │       │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────┤
│[{"name":"a1","s":1,"key":0},{},{"key":2},{"key":2},{},{"key":3},{"key│124    │
│":3},{},{"key":4},{"key":4},{},{"name":"a4","s":123,"key":6}]         │       │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────┤
│[{"name":"a2","s":10,"key":1},{},{"key":2},{"key":2},{},{"key":3},{"ke│21     │
│y":3},{},{"key":4},{"key":4},{},{"name":"a3","s":11,"key":5}]         │       │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────┤
│[{"name":"a1","s":1,"key":0},{},{"key":2},{"key":2},{},{"key":3},{"key│12     │
│":3},{},{"key":4},{"key":4},{},{"name":"a3","s":11,"key":5}]          │       │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "score".

You might look at ORDPATH, which sorts on hierarchy. You might sort the path by score and then you use ORDPATH. There is a function for this at [GitHub](https://github.com/waigitdas/Neo4j-Genealogy-PlugIns/blob/main/java%20classes/graph/ordpath.java). The input requires numbers, so you might have to use the score  or relationship ids.

You can see how this is implemented in the [blog post](https://www.wai.md/post/ordpath-computing-genealogy-descendancy-trees)

It would be nice if Neo4j developers incorporated this into APOC.